# Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1559a8200

Tags: swift, swift2, selector

I'm receiving a

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1559a8200

The selector referenced in the error message is:

```
[SoloCheck.DirectorFormCell seeDirectorReportDidTap:]
```

The code to add the target is as follows:

```
cell.seeDirectorReport.addTarget(cell.seeDirectorReport, action: #selector(CompanyFreeReportVC.seeDirectorReportDidTap(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

The implementation of that method as as follows:

```
func seeDirectorReportDidTap(sender: UIButton) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("OpenCompanyDocumentsSegue", sender: sender.tag)
}
```

I changed the code to

```
cell.seeDirectorReport.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CompanyFreeReportVC.seeDirectorReportDidTap(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

and the error stays the same:

```
2017-04-20 15:53:19.806 SoloCheck[12035:1267396] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UISearchController: 0x15ef187a0>)
2017-04-20 15:53:19.854 SoloCheck[12035:] <GMR/INFO> App measurement v.2003000 started
2017-04-20 15:53:19.854 SoloCheck[12035:] <GMR/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -GMRDebugEnabled (see )
2017-04-20 15:53:20.009 SoloCheck[12035:1267396] [Crashlytics] Version 3.7.0 (102)
2017-04-20 15:53:37.786 SoloCheck[12035:1267396] -[SoloCheck.DirectorFormCell seeDirectorReportDidTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f154600
2017-04-20 15:53:37.794 SoloCheck[12035:1267396] WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.14 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:48): Uncaught exception: -[SoloCheck.DirectorFormCell seeDirectorReportDidTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f154600
2017-04-20 15:53:42.837 SoloCheck[12035:1267396] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SoloCheck.DirectorFormCell seeDirectorReportDidTap:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15f154600'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18324d900 0x1828bbf80 0x18325461c 0x1832515b8 0x18315568c 0x187f77e50 0x187f77dcc 0x187f5fa88 0x187f776e4 0x187f30294 0x187f70820 0x187f6fe1c 0x187f404cc 0x187f3e794 0x183204efc 0x183204990 0x183202690 0x183131680 0x184640088 0x187fa8d90 0x1000b544c 0x182cd28b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: what was the unrecognized selector, it usually is in the error message

Comment: [SoloCheck.DirectorFormCell seeDirectorReportDidTap:] - I also wanted to put a value in the button tag and retrieve in the seeDirectorReportDidTap method is it possible?

Comment: Your `#selector` has specified a method of a view controller, but the `target` appears to be something else. To what does the `cell.seeDirectReport` refer?

Comment: refers a UIButton in a custom Cell class

Comment: Yeah, but the `target` is the object in which the `selector` will be called, not the object that initiated the call. You want to specify your view controller as the first parameter of `addTarget`.

Comment: Ok, I understand what the first parameter is now but still getting the same exact error

Comment: I find it surprising that the error is exactly the same, with the same selector references, even after you changed the `target`. Edit the question, adding to the bottom of the question what you tried and the _full_ error message (including the selector). I suspect the selector in the error message is going to be different. But, regardless of the details, your error is just telling you that your `target` has not referenced the method you referenced in your `action`. So, identify whether you supplied the wrong target or whatever.

Comment: In your revised example, you set the `target` to `self`. What is `self`? (I.e. where do you have this code? Is this inside the custom cell class implementation? If so, `self` would refer to the cell, which, given that you have implemented your `seeDirectorReportDidTap` method in the view controller, it wouldn't work. If your `action` selector is in the view controller, then the `target` must be the view controller, not the cell. Either that or move the `seeDirectorReportDidTap` into the cell, and then have some other mechanism to inform the view controller that some action has taken place.

Answer (score 1):

This error is just telling you that your `target` has not referenced the method you referenced in your `action`. So, identify whether you supplied the wrong target or the wrong `action`.

The first parameter of `addTarget` is the object that implemented the `action` selector. I'm inferring from your `#selector(CompanyFreeReportVC.seeDirectorReportDidTap(_:))` that you've implemented `seeDirectorReportDidTap` in your view controller. You therefore need to specify your view controller as the first parameter of `addTarget`.

Comment: I never used Swift 2 but shouldn't the selector's signature be different? There is no `_` in the actual `seeDirectorReportDidTap` function declaration so shouldn't the selector be something like: `#selector(CompanyFreeReportVC.seeDirectorReportDidTap(sender:))` ?

Comment: I saw that somewhere and tried but it won't even compile it says 'Type 'CompanyFreeReportVC' has no member 'seeDirectorReportDidTap(sender‌​:)'